# Difference between Search result from Admin console and solr/browse

Tags: solr

I have imported my xml documents from oracle database and indexed them. When I search *:* in admin console I do get results. My xml format is not close to what solr expects. but still when I search for any word that is part of my xml document Solr displays whole xml document. for example if I search for word "voicemail" solr displays xml documents that has word "voicemail"

Now when I go to solr/browse and give *:* I do see some thing but each result is like below (no data) even if i search for same word "voicemail" I am getting below. Can some body !!!!!!please Advice!!!!!

Price: 
Features: 
In Stock

there are only two things I can think off, one is settings in solrconfig.xml(like below).

```
<requestHandler name="/browse" class="solr.SearchHandler">
<lst name="defaults">
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>


       <str name="wt">velocity</str>

       <str name="v.template">browse</str>
       <str name="v.layout">layout</str>
       <str name="title">Solritas</str>

       <str name="df">text</str>
       <str name="defType">edismax</str>
       <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
       <str name="rows">10</str>
       <str name="fl">*,score</str>
       <str name="mlt.qf">
         text^0.5 features^1.0 name^1.2 sku^1.5 id^10.0 manu^1.1 cat^1.4 
       </str>
       <str name="mlt.fl">text,features,name,sku,id,manu,cat</str>
       <int name="mlt.count">3</int>
       <str name="qf">
          text^0.5 features^1.0 name^1.2 sku^1.5 id^10.0 manu^1.1 cat^1.4 
       </str>
```

Comment: what query are you giving to solr that returns no results?

Answer (score 0):

You wil find browse.vm and product.vm file in solr/collection/conf/velocity folder.
By default Solr comes with one default example on books data. hence the ui part is showing
 **Price: Features: In Stock**

If you want to show the meta data of your index fields on browse page then you have to modify product-doc.vm file on above mentioned location and you have to add your meta data field name in that.